# Regex Replace w Match

Tags: python, regex, replace, match

I have names like "Western Michigan" "Northern Illinois" and I need to change them to "W Michigan" and "N Illinois".  The following is the closest I have but this fails cause let's say I match the word "Western Michigan" it throws an error and says \2 is an unmatched group (\3 seems to return the W I want).  (this is python)

```
re.sub("^((S)outhern|(E)astern|(W)estern|(N)orthern)", r"\2", long_name)
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this?

Answer (score 4):

You have 5 capturing groups - but that's already been explained.  You can get what you want easily if you reduce it to 1 capturing group, but it's a little subtle.  First you use a "positive lookahead assertion" to ensure that you're looking at one of the "long words" of interest.  An assertion doesn't *match* anything, though.  It just constrains the search.  Then you can capture the letter following, and consume the rest.  Like so:

```
pat = r"""(?=Southern|Eastern|Western|Northern)  # looking at one of these words
          (.)   # just capture the first character
          (outhern|astern|estern|orthern)  # and consume the rest"""
pat = re.compile(pat, re.VERBOSE)
pat.sub(r"\1", long_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing a replace pattern, you can pass a callback:

```
 re.sub("^(?P<word>Southern|Eastern|Western|Northern)", 
        lambda match: match.group('word')[0], 
        'Northern Illinois')
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly.  could you please explain the syntax.  i dont understand 1) "?P<word>"    2)how this lambda works here

Comment: `(?P<group_name> [your pattern] )` denotes a named group, so instead of referencing it by number (`match.group(1)`), you can reference it by name `match.group('group_name')`. More on this here: http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 2):

The grouping for the regular expression is by the n<sup>th</sup> open paren:

```
#        12          3         4         5
re.sub("^((S)outhern|(E)astern|(W)estern|(N)orthern)", r"\2", long_name)
```

Thus, the 2nd group would be 'S' if it matched, the third group the 'E' if it matched, and so on.

To rectify this, instead match the word and use the first character of the matched word.

Comment: I like your explanation of the problem but I think your answer could benefit from a concrete example of what you mean by "match the word and use the first character" since it isn't obvious from just that text.

Comment: absolutely it could, the problem is that while I'm rather familiar with some of the nuances of regular expressions, my python skills are rather lacking and I'm certain I couldn't produce something properly pythonic for it.  If another answer wants to incorporate the two lines that I've got into their own, I would be quite happy to delete my own answer as redundant.